# Execute rake command inside bash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash, shell

I am seeing many times the question about execution of bash files inside rake (task) files.

My question is, how to execute a rake command inside the bash file?
I have a `migrate.sh` file inside each rails app on my server and I'm using a general `publish.sh`. All of this runs ok.

Then, I have a command like `rake tmp:clear assets:clean log:clear RAILS_ENV=production` inside each `migrate.sh` that gives me a `rake: command not found` error.

Help?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install rake`?

Comment: maybe a profile issue

Comment: I think it may be a profile issue yes. I'm running some tests to make sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

klashxx's supposition was correct. It was a permissions/profile issue. I had change my user to root to be able to do other previous tasks and found out that my root was not able to run rake tasks.

This will not be an issue on production server though.

Thanks [klashxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1200821/klashxx)

Answer (score 1):

Basically `rake` is not resolved as the `PATH` variable is not correct. You can try doing `echo $PATH`. Also you can create a bash script and provide some environment variables required by rake like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

GEM_HOME=/home/tuxdna/.gems
SHELL=/bin/bash
USER=tuxdna
PATH=/home/tuxdna/.gems/bin:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games
GEM_PATH=/home/tuxdna/.gems:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

cd ~/somesite
export RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake mytask:task1
```